# Compute $f(4)$ and $\left(\frac{\sqrt x}{y^3}\right)$ at $x=4$

Tags: calculus

> Compute $f(4)$ and ${d\over dx}{f\over g}$ at $x=4$, using the following information.
>
> $$f'(4)=5$$
> $$g'(4)=12$$
> $$(fg)(4)=f(4)g(4)=2$$
> $$g(4)=6$$

Here is my work so far:

${d\over dx}{f\over g}$ at $x=4 ={f'(4)g(4)-f(4)g'(4)\over g(4)^2}$

$={5*6-f(4)12\over 6^2}$

$={30-12f(4)\over 36}$

I know the solution to be ${13\over 18}$, but I'm not sure how to get there, as my method doesn't seem to be working out. Any hints or ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: If $f(4)g(4)=2,$ and $g(4)=6$, I think you're a single substitution away from completing the exercise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're told that $g(4)=6$, and that $f(4)\cdot g(4)=2$. Can you figure out what $f(4)$ must be?

Comment: That suggests that f(4) must be 1/3. How does that relate to my final answer?

Comment: Never mind, I see what you meant. Thanks for the tip.